# Image array not being read

Tags: javascript, html

The code below is intended to display a set of images numbered x.jpg (where x is a number starting at 0 and going up to n) in normal order, then in reverse order. The final product is meant to do it only in reverse order but the normal order part was put in for testing purposes. It currently displays the images in normal order correctly, but does not display them in reverse order. I understand that this sort of functionality was not really intended to be done in normal javascript alone but it would be helpful to know why this does not work.

```
<script>
        var counter = 0;
        var imageArray = [];

        function getImg(){
            var imgURL = "images/" + counter + ".jpg";

            var img = new Image();
            img.src=imgURL;

            imageArray.push(img)
            document.getElementById('imageList').appendChild(img);

            counter++;

            img.onload = function(){
                //alert(this.width);
                if(this.width!=0){
                    getImg();
                }
                else{
                    var popped = imageArray.pop()
                }
            }
        }
        function reverseImg() {

            imageArray.reverse();
            for (i=1; i<imageArray.length; i++) {

                image = imageArray[i]
                document.getElementById('reversedList').appendChild(image);
            }

        }

        getImg();
        reverseImg();

</script>
```

Comment: This is not just  a scoping and timing issue. Your `getImg` code is _asynchronous_. While the first image is __being loaded__, `reverseImg()` is already called. That call should only happen _after_ the last `onload` completes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you call `reverseImg`, `imageArray` has only one image in it, and you're skipping that in your `for` loop by starting with 1. The code in the `onload` callbacks in `getImg` doesn't run until later, when the first image loads.

If you want the images displayed in reverse order with a time delay in-between, you need to do something like `getImg` with its `onload` behavior (but I'd handle `error` as well), but starting by reversing the array first. Or actually, there's no need for the array at all, just start with `n` (the last image) and count backward, creating the `Image` elements within the callbacks.

For example:

```js
function reverseImg() {
    var n = 9;
    tick();
    
    function tick() {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        if (n > 0) {
            // When this image loads/fails, load the next
            img.addEventListener("load", tick);
            img.addEventListener("error", tick);
        }
        // Show this image
        img.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/100/000080/FFFFFF?text=Image%20" + n;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        --n;
    }
}
reverseImg();
```

```css
img {
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of images is subject to change and this is what the array is for. The idea is that it tries to load all images in turn and on the first failure it stops.

Comment: @deathwing_destroyer - That's fine, you can adjust the above quite easily to do that.